# How to switch data from two tables based on filter in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables which have counts and sales based on dates and one of them also have customer ID. The counts are not same when we see by customer and summary. I also have customer filter on my dashboard. What I want to achieve is if no customer is selected the count should come from summary table otherwise it should come from customer if multiple or one is selected in the filter.

Customer Table

[image]

Summary Table

[image]

Any hints, I have tried lookupvalue function but I cant put date as search value from date table.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use Measures, instead of creating calculated tables to obtain those metrics. Also, summarized tables would not have the same filter context your are looking for.

### Measure 1

```
Total Customers = 
 DISTINCTCOUNT('Customer Table'[CustomerID])
```

### Measure 2

```
Total Sales = 
 SUM ( 'Customer Table'[Sales])
```

Comment: This measures will not give me correct result, I want to get count field value. If user select filter as customer ID 1 it should give me count as 5 and if user remove filter on customer it should change to 8. This is why I have created two tables and had relation with date. Is this possible?

Comment: Well in that case you can use `SUM('Customer Table'[Count])`. Using a summarized table is a bad idea.

Comment: The issue is the count is different when we filter by customer Id so I have one person working for two customers so when we filter by customer it should be counted separately for each customer but when I remove Customer filter it is one person. I have customer ID in data so it will always count same person twice when no customer is selected.